# SQL Server / T-SQL need to modify dynamic stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that dynamically generates `MERGE` TSQL statements to handle SCD Type 1 updates between the given Dimension / Staging table dump.

Here is the T-SQL code (modified from the original code by Alex Whittles):

```
USE [OPPY_DWUSD]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateMerge]
/***************************************************************
*                                                              *
*   Script for use with blog post                              *
*     "Automating T-SQL Merge to load Dimensions (SCD)"        *
*     http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2012/04/automating-t-sql-merge-to-load-dimensions-scd
*                                                              *   
*   Posted: 6th April 2012                                     *
*                                                              *
*   By: Alex Whittles - Purple Frog Business Intelligence      *
*       www.PurpleFrogSystems.com                              *
*                                                              *
*   All code samples are provided “AS IS” without warranty of  *
*   any kind, either express or implied, including but not     *
*   limited to the implied warranties of merchantability       *
*   and/or fitness for a particular purpose.                   *
*                                                              *
***************************************************************/

@Dimension  varchar(50),
@Schema     varchar(50),
@ETLTable   varchar(50),
@ETLSchema  varchar(50),
@Execute    bit=0  --Should the resulting merge be returned or executed
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Create Carriage return variable to format the resulting query
DECLARE @crlf char(2)
SET @crlf = CHAR(13)


--Find out which Audit fields are used
DECLARE @UseIsInferred bit
DECLARE @UseFirstCreated bit
DECLARE @UseValidTo bit
DECLARE @UseIsRowCurrent bit
DECLARE @UseLastUpdated bit

SET @UseIsInferred = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(1) 
FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE       s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name = 'IsInferred'
),0)

SET @UseFirstCreated= ISNULL((SELECT MAX(1) 
FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE       s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name = 'FirstCreated'
),0)

SET @UseValidTo = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(1) 
FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE       s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name = 'ValidTo'
),0)

SET @UseIsRowCurrent = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(1) 
FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE       s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name = 'IsRowCurrent'
),0)

SET @UseLastUpdated = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(1) 
FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE       s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name = 'LastUpdated'
),0)


--Identify the business key column(s)
--Also define what the null replacement should be
DECLARE myCurBK Cursor FOR 
SELECT c.name
    , CASE WHEN ty.name IN ('text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar') THEN ''''''
        WHEN ty.name IN ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'real', 'money', 'float', 'bit', 'decimal', 'numeric','smallmoney','bigint') THEN '0'
        WHEN ty.name IN ('date', 'datetime') THEN '''19000101'''
        ELSE 'NULL' END AS NullRep
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties ep 
         ON t.object_id=ep.major_id
        AND c.column_id=ep.minor_id
        AND ep.class=1
        AND ep.name='SCD'
WHERE s.name = @Schema
    AND t.name = @Dimension
    AND ep.value = 'BK'
ORDER BY c.column_id

--Identify all fields to be merged (Exclude Type 0)
DECLARE myCurType1 Cursor
FOR SELECT c.name
    , CASE WHEN ty.name IN ('text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar') THEN ''''''
        WHEN ty.name IN ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'real', 'money', 'float', 'bit', 'decimal', 'numeric','smallmoney','bigint') THEN '0'
        WHEN ty.name IN ('date', 'datetime') THEN '''19000101'''
        ELSE 'NULL' END AS NullRep
    FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties ep 
             ON t.object_id=ep.major_id
            AND c.column_id=ep.minor_id
            AND ep.class=1
            AND ep.name='SCD'
    WHERE s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.is_identity=0
        AND ISNULL(ep.value,'1') NOT IN ('0', 'Audit', 'BK')
    ORDER BY c.column_id ASC

--Identify all fields for insert
DECLARE myCurAll Cursor
FOR SELECT c.name
    , CASE WHEN ty.name IN ('text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar') THEN ''''''
        WHEN ty.name IN ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'real', 'money', 'float', 'bit', 'decimal', 'numeric','smallmoney','bigint') THEN '0'
        WHEN ty.name IN ('date', 'datetime') THEN '''19000101'''
        ELSE 'NULL' END AS NullRep
    FROM sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
    WHERE s.name = @Schema
        AND t.name = @Dimension
        AND c.name NOT IN ('LastUpdated', 'IsInferred', 'FirstCreated', 'ValidTo', 'IsRowCurrent')
        AND c.is_identity=0
    ORDER BY c.column_id ASC

DECLARE @Field varchar(255)
DECLARE @NullRep varchar(20)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL2 varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL3 varchar(max)

--Now start building up the dynamic SQL

SET @SQL ='MERGE [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Dimension + '] AS Target'
SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + 'USING [' + @ETLSchema + '].[' + @ETLTable + '] AS Source'

OPEN myCurBK
FETCH NEXT FROM myCurBK INTO @Field, @NullRep
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '       ON Target.' + '[' + @Field + ']' +  ' = Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCurBK INTO @Field, @NullRep
    END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '       AND Target.' + '[' + @Field + ']' +  ' = Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCurBK INTO @Field, @NullRep
END
CLOSE myCurBK

IF @UseIsRowCurrent>0   SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '       AND Target.IsRowCurrent=1'

SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '    WHEN MATCHED'

OPEN myCurType1
FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep

IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '       AND (ISNULL(Target.' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ',' + @NullRep + ') <> ISNULL(Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ',' + @NullRep + ')'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep
    END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '       OR ISNULL(Target.' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ',' + @NullRep + ') <> ISNULL(Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ',' + @NullRep + ')'
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep
END
CLOSE myCurType1

SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + '      )'
SET @SQL2 = '    THEN UPDATE SET'

OPEN myCurType1
FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL2 = @SQL2 + @crlf + '       ' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ' = Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep
    END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
        SET @SQL2 = @SQL2 + @crlf + '      ,' + '[' + @Field + ']' + ' = Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCurType1 INTO @Field, @NullRep
END
CLOSE myCurType1

IF @UseLastUpdated>0   SET @SQL2 = @SQL2 + @crlf + '      ,LastUpdated = GetDate()'

SET @SQL3 = '    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN'
SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '         INSERT ('

OPEN myCurAll
FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ' + '[' + @Field + ']'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
    END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,' + '[' + @Field + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
END
CLOSE myCurAll


IF @UseIsInferred>0     SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,IsInferred'
IF @UseFirstCreated>0   SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,FirstCreated'
IF @UseValidTo>0        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,ValidTo'
IF @UseIsRowCurrent>0   SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,IsRowCurrent'
IF @UseLastUpdated>0    SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,LastUpdated'
SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '         ) VALUES ('

OPEN myCurAll
FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '            Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
    END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,Source.' + '[' + @Field + ']'
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCurAll INTO @Field, @NullRep
END
CLOSE myCurAll    

IF @UseIsInferred>0     SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,0'
IF @UseFirstCreated>0   SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,GetDate()'
IF @UseValidTo>0        SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,NULL'
IF @UseIsRowCurrent>0   SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,1'
IF @UseLastUpdated>0    SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '           ,GetDate()'
SET @SQL3 = @SQL3 + @crlf + '         );'

--clean up
DEALLOCATE myCurType1
DEALLOCATE myCurAll
DEALLOCATE myCurBK

IF @Execute = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@SQL + @SQL2 + @SQL3)           
END
ELSE
BEGIN    
    PRINT @SQL
    PRINT @SQL2
    PRINT @SQL3
END

END
```

In the stored procedure above, when I pass in the variables, it produces this code:

```
MERGE [DIM].[COMPANY] AS Target
USING [DBO].[DWUSD_LIVE] AS Source
    ON Target.[comp] = Source.[comp]
 WHEN MATCHED
    AND (ISNULL(Target.[comp name],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[comp name],'')
    OR ISNULL(Target.[comp description],'') <> ISNULL(Source.[comp description],'')
   )
THEN UPDATE SET
    [comp name] = Source.[comp name]
   ,[comp description] = Source.[comp description]
   ,LastUpdated = GetDate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (
        [comp]
        ,[comp name]
        ,[comp description]
        ,FirstCreated
        ,LastUpdated
      ) VALUES (
         Source.[comp]
        ,Source.[comp name]
        ,Source.[comp description]
        ,GetDate()
        ,GetDate()
      );
```

What I need to be able to do is add a `DISTINCT` `SELECT` subquery at the beginning...

```
MERGE [dim].[Company] AS Target
USING (
SELECT DISTINCT 
[COMP NAME],
[COMP DESCRIPTION],
[COMP]
FROM [dbo].[DWUSD_LIVE]
) AS Source
```

So that when it looks at the source (staging table) it does a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the same columns found in the dimension but not including the audit columns (`FirstCreated` / `LastUpdated`).

My staging table has duplicate records, thus I only need to `SELECT DISTINCT` otherwise I end up with multiple records in my dimension.

Comment: The FirstCreated and LastUpdated columns get populated down below during the WHEN MATCHED & WHEN NOT MATCHED part of the syntax. What I am looking to do is add the SELECT DISTINCT TSQL for "AS Source" at the start of the generated syntax.

Comment: OOps, sorry, I see you are using Getdate().  Never mind...  I'll delete the prvious...

Comment: So, why can't you just use SELECT DISTINCT as you've shown?  What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you pass the table you want to use as a source to the stored procedure in these variables:

```
@ETLTable   varchar(50),
@ETLSchema  varchar(50),
```

Those same variables are used in defining the source:

```
--Now start building up the dynamic SQL

SET @SQL ='MERGE [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Dimension + '] AS Target'
SET @SQL = @SQL + @crlf + 'USING [' + @ETLSchema + '].[' + @ETLTable + '] AS Source'
```

I believe, as long as you have the same columns you would need from the actual source table, you can take the distinct query you want to use, create a view with it and pass that table to the stored proc.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwDWUSD_LIVE
AS 
SELECT DISTINCT 
[COMP NAME],
[COMP DESCRIPTION],
[COMP]
FROM [dbo].[DWUSD_LIVE]
GO
```

The exec statement would look something like:

```
EXEC [dbo].[GenerateMerge] 'COMPANY', 'DIM', 'vwDWUSD_LIVE', 'DBO', 1
```

Also, you won't have to modify the stored proc, which looks like it may be called by other processes and if you have this same situation with other tables, you can apply a similar solution.

Comment: Using a view and doing a SELECT DISTINCT in the view works exactly as I wanted this; thank you Vinnie!